# Changing Internationalization in Angular to Japanese

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, locale

I'm working on an application where I need to translate some data into Japanese. The primary issue is getting the currency to display in Yen and not Dollars.

First off I downloaded the angular-18n package into my application, and then I added a script tag in my html in order to reference the Japanese locale.

Even after doing this, my currency still shows $ signs and not Yen.

Let me know if you have any ideas or have run into a similar issue in the past. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a default currency code in your Module.

> Provide this token to set the default currency code your application uses for CurrencyPipe when there is no currency code passed into it.

```js
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        { provide: DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE, useValue: 'JPY' }
    ],
})
```

See the documentation for the [`DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE`](https://angular.io/api/core/DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE) injection token for more details.

Comment: Simply switching UI locale and displaying a different currency symbol isn't necessarily correct.  When storing your data, you'll need to account for what monetary unit your value is. Simply displaying a USD $ amount with a Yen symbol will be wrong (unless you account for the current exchange rate).